# PyQGIS - QgsSpatialIndex.intersects returns unexpected results

Tags: pyqgis, intersection

I have a polygon and a line. The line starts very close to the polygon but the end vertex is further away. I create a rectangle around start and end vertex. The spatial index of the polygon is used for intersecting both rectangle. I expect only one rectangle to intersect but I get intersection for both. Why?
The screenshot shows the extent of the rectangles - only one intersects with the polygon.

QGIS 2.18, Win7.

Data source: SHP files.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# is start/endpoint of section close to a buildung within tolerance?
tolarance_in_meters = 0.5

# Get the active layer
layer1 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("line")[0]
layer1.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
layer2 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]
layer2.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')

# create indices
index1 = QgsSpatialIndex(layer1.getFeatures())
index2 = QgsSpatialIndex(layer2.getFeatures())

# create a memory layer with two points
polyTemp =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'temp' , "memory")
polyTemp.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
pr = polyTemp.dataProvider() 

def getRectangle(point, size):
    x = point.x()
    y = point.y()    
    ll_x = x-size
    ll_y = y-size
    ur_x = x+size
    ur_y = y+size    
    return QgsRectangle(ll_x,ll_y,ur_x,ur_y)   

iter = layer1.getFeatures()
for feature in iter:       
    # feature is a line (not a multi - line)
    geom = feature.geometry()
    # we need first and last vertex
    vertices = geom.asPolyline()    
    qgis_point_vFirst = geom.vertexAt(0)
    qgis_point_vLast = geom.vertexAt(num_vertices-1)    
    rect1 = getRectangle(qgis_point_vFirst, tolarance_in_meters)
    intersection_vFirst_ids =  index2.intersects(rect1)
    rect2 = getRectangle(qgis_point_vLast, tolarance_in_meters)
    intersection_vLast_ids =  index2.intersects(rect2)   

    # add the rectangles    
    pt = QgsFeature()         
    r =  QgsGeometry().fromRect(rect1)
    pt.setGeometry(r)
    pr.addFeatures([pt])
    pt = QgsFeature()     
    r =  QgsGeometry().fromRect(rect2)
    pt.setGeometry(r)
    pr.addFeatures([pt])


   numInter1 = len(intersection_vFirst_ids)
   numInter2 = len(intersection_vLast_ids)

   print("num intersections: {0}, {1}".format(len(intersection_vFirst_ids), len(intersection_vLast_ids)))

polyTemp.updateExtents()
polyTemp.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([polyTemp])
```

[image]

Comment: Draw the bounding box of the big polygon and you will see immediately why.

Comment: To clarify, create an envelope which is north-south and west-east oriented box.